# To extract records from file based on the latest date and store in a new file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a file with different balances for a particular account. And every day these balance changes. What I want to do is extract balance record of a particular account based on the latest date.

I am following an approach where I am adding the date into the first column of records manually using an `awk` script but taking date from the file name since I do not get date in my records. Next I want to sort the records based on the Account number and want to extract the record with latest date in another file.

Can anybody help me with this?

Till now I have written this code and I am unable to sort and extract the data into the other file

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

f=mainfile_20151201.dat
s=`echo $f | cut -c 16-23`
echo "$f -> $s"

awk -F "~" 'BEGIN { OFS = "~"; ORS = "\n" ; date='$s' ; IFS = "~"} { $1=date"~"$1 ; print  }' mainfile_20151201.dat > tempdate

awk -F "~" 'BEGIN { OFS = "~"; ORS = "\n" ;  IFS = "~"} { $1 ; print  }' tempdate > newfile
```

Sample data:

```
AccountNumber~~0~149038.40000000~149038.4~0.00000000~0.00000000~0.00000000
```

Please note that the data in the 4th field changes everyday

Comment: Your input file only contains 1 line? If not then your posted sample data doesn't represent your real data and so is not useful. Edit your question to include concise, testable and truly representative sample input plus the output you expect given that input.

Answer (score 0):

If your main file is always going to be in the format "something_date" this should do the job ok.

```
#!/bin/bash
f=mainfile_20151201.dat
s=`echo $f | cut -d"_" -f2`
echo "$f -> $s"
awk -F "~" 'BEGIN { OFS = "~"; ORS = "\n" ; date='$s' ; IFS = "~"} { $1=date"~"$1 ; print  }' mainfile_20151201.dat > tempdate
awk -F "~" 'BEGIN { OFS = "~"; ORS = "\n" ;  IFS = "~"} { $1 ; print  }' tempdate > newfile
 rm tempdate

sort -u -t~ -k 2 <newfile >newfile.s
#sort by unique arange by field 2 then field 1 (default action)

d=$(cat newfile.s | head -1 | cut -d"~" -f1) #get first date
a=$(cat newfile.s | head -1 | cut -d"~" -f2) #get first account number

while read line; do
 d2=`echo "$line" | cut -d"~" -f1` #get date from line
 a2=`echo "$line" | cut -d"~" -f2` #get account from line
if [[ $a2 == $a ]] && [[ $d2 > $d ]] || [[ $d2 == $d ]];then #if acount are same but date is 'bigger' OR the same
 sed -i '$ d' output.txt #remove last line of file
 echo "$line" >> output.txt #append to file
 a="$a2" #set new account for later
 d="$d2" #set new date for later
else
 a="$a2"
 d="$d2"
 echo "$line" >>output.txt
fi
done <newfile.s #while input declaration
```

Note:  This worked with the sample from your comment but will definitely need to be tweeked for your needs.  At any rate, it should be enough to get you going.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This is helpful in sorting the file. But my question is how to extract the lastest date entry from output file into another file.
For example if we consider your output:
20151201~1232455767~~0~149038.40000000~149038.4~0.00000000~0.00000000~0.00000000
20151202~1232455767~~0~178638.40000000~149038.4~0.00000000~0.00000000~0.00000000
20151201~2341245456~~0~149038.40000000~149038.4~0.00000000~0.00000000~0.00000000
The first 2 records have same account number and I want to get 20151202 record in my output file where balance(5th field) in greater.

Is it possible?

Comment: It is, but the only solution I could give you would be a rather lengthy while loop.  I'm sure somebody with more experience than I could suggest a fancy one liner using `awk` or `perl` to filter the output.